# How to make ubuntu local repo contain Server-Edition packages only (non-gui)

Tags: server, apt, localrepository

Ubuntu repo is huge. I'm using Ubuntu Server Edition. How to create local repo which contain only packages intended for Server Edition?

I don't need something like audio/video player/editor, image editor, games, etc.

I need something like DNS server, HTTP Server, etc.

I hope that local repo not as big as default one.

Thank you.